# Como posso mudar a URL da minha pagina inicial no Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Tenho um site em WordPress, quando acesso ele fica `dominio.com`, mas quero que somente a `index` dele mude para `www.dominio.com/home`.

Ou seja, quando acessar `www.dominio.com`, mudar para `www.dominio.com/home` (Ou seja, só quando acessar a pagina inicial, as outras paginas ficam como estão).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta colocar esse trecho no `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
DirectoryIndex home.php

</IfModule>
```

Assim `home.php` terá prioridade sobre seus arquivos e não aparecerá a extenção do arquivo `.php`

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro: http://prntscr.com/j2afy1

Comment: você deve renomear o arquivo `index.php` para `home.php`

Comment: Apenas para entender, quando adicionado a linha `DirectoryIndex home.php`, quer dizer que ao ir para `example.com` ele buscará o arquivo definido na linha (`home.php`), se não exsitir ele vai mostrar uma lista de arquivos que existe naquele diretório, como na imagem